# iphone sqlite quotes problem

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a problem with a following sqlite query:

```
sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into table_name(height)values('%@')",heightarray];
```

I am getting `heightarray` from XML, the value of `heightarray` is:

```
array =  ( "5'0\"-5'3\"",
           "5'4\"-5'8\"",
           "5'9\"-6'0\"" )
```

The \" is added implicitly for some reason, I don't know why?

It is causing problem. please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into table_name(height)values(?)"];
```

and then use

```
sqlite3_bind_text
```

If you're using sqlite try this wrapper it helps a lot
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

There are detailed examples how to use it.

Comment: @user$$3279  This is my bind statement

sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [ht UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

I am getting the following exception.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI UTF8String]:

Comment: @443279 thts really tough. I have around 11 fields. I get the data from the server n parsing it.